# objective-c struct properties are released before usage

Tags: objective-c, struct, automatic-ref-counting

I have a struct in my Objective-C code like this >

```
typedef struct {
__unsafe_unretained NSString *string1;
__unsafe_unretained NSString *string2;
__unsafe_unretained NSString *string3;
__unsafe_unretained NSString *string4;
__unsafe_unretained NSString *string5;
.
.
.
__unsafe_unretained NSString *string10;

} MyStruct;
```

In my model class I store these structs in an array declared

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myStructArray;
```

I construct this in my .m file during runtime like this

```
NSMutableArray *myTempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *jsonDict in jsonArray)
{
 MyStruct stringsStruct = parseWithDictionary(jsonDict);
 [myTempArray addObject:[NSValue value:&stringsStruct withObjCType:@encode(MyStruct)]];
}
myObject.myStructArray = myTempArray;
```

The problem is when I try to access this after parsing / constructing the inside objects are already deallocated & I received the error

```
-[CFURL length]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

Here is how I access the properties later by the way,

```
 MyStruct myStruct; 
[[myObject.myStructArray objectAtIndex:someIndex] getValue:&myStruct];
NSLog(@"%@",myStruct.string1); // << bam! crash
```

How do I fix this ? Is there a way to make sure the objects objects remain intact without deallocing until i'm done with it ? I'm using ARC & cannot remove with __unsafe_unretained hence.

Comment: I don't understand what the purpose of this struct is. Why isn't it an object or a nested array. What sort of benefit do you get from it being a struct to start with? Also can you access them directly after creation properly, basically are you sure their initializing to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly told ARC to get out of the way by using `__unsafe_unretained` and it's the only way to get a struct hold object values. This doesn't come without a price: you pay the memory management fee.

You manually have to retain/release any object you place in your structs by using `CFRelease`/`CFRetain` and this is **very** error prone.

Let me stress a point: __***UNSAFE***_unretained. The name hasn't been picked randomly.

My advice is: stop using structs and turn them into objects.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string1;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string2;
...
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string10;

@end
```

It's better under many point of views:

- you get memory management "for free" with ARC
- you can define convenience methods in the class
- it's more idiomatic Objective-C wise

Comment: yeah in objective-c it seems very strange to use a struct to do memory management.

Comment: Not that strange, there are many notable examples, like the whole `Core Foundation`. However the evolution of the language is headed towards higher levels of abstractions. ARC set a big step in this direction, so it's better to jump on the train and start modernizing legacy code.

Comment: Thanks, Yes using objects is quite simple & the correct way to do it. I was *really* curious on how to do the manual memory handling for the structs in this case. This was not aimed towards productivity but rather curiosity :)

Comment: @nsuinteger you're welcome. If you feel like the answer helper you, consider accepting it ;)